# ShieldUI Controls in Toolbar?

Tags: gridview, grid, shieldui

Is it possible to put other controls, besides button, in the toolbar?

I'd like to move my column hiding and filtering controls to the toolbar as well as make the Export to Excel button smaller and floated right.

**Update**

```
<div class="grid-config">
    <div>
        Column:
        <select id="columnChooser">
            @Html.Raw(ViewBag.columnChooser) // loads columns dynamically
        </select>
        <button id="hideColumn">Hide Column</button>
        <button id="showColumn">Show Column</button>
        <div id="filter">
            Search as you type:&nbsp;<input type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [toolbar.template](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/settings/toolbar/template) setting to define a function from which to add elements to the toolbar dynamically.

To make the export button smaller, you can use the [toolbar.buttons.cls](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/settings/toolbar/buttons) option to add a class for the button. Or, you can render your own button in the toolbar, and call the Grid's `exportExcel()` function when clicked.

Comment: I have updated my post to show the code for my filter/ column chooser area. How would I put that in the toolbar?

Comment: Also, setting the `toolbar.button.cls` didn't work correctly to set the button `float:right;`.

Comment: Are you passing a valid CSS class name? Using inline styles like "float:right" will not work...

Comment: Yes. Seems I also had to do this for it to work correctly: `.sui-toolbar {overflow:auto;}`

Comment: Who is making all the tag edits? Why would they be adding `grid-view` and `grid`? Those are not ShieldUI tags.